# connecting to remote oracle database in SQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to do some data migration between two oracle databases that in different servers.  I've thought of some ways to do it like writing a jdbc program but i think the best way is to do it in SQL itself.  I can also copy the entire table over to the database I am migrating to but these tables are big and doesnt seem like a "elegant" solution.

Is it possible to open a connection to one DB in SQL developer then connect to the other one using SQL and writing update/insert functions on tables as if they were both in the same connection?

I have read some examples on creating linked tables but none seem to be oracle specific or tell me how to open the external connection by supplying it the server hostname/port/SID/user credentials.

thanks for the help!

Comment: Go read the [Oracle Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/ds_admin002.htm#ADMIN12150)  There is absolutely no reason to write any java code to do this.

Answer (score 1):

If you create a Database Link, you can just select a from different database by querying `TABLENAME@dblink`.

You can create such a link using the [`CREATE DATABASE LINK`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5005.htm) statement.

Answer (score 0):

It depends if its a one time thing or a normal process and if you need to do ETL (Extract, Transform and Load) or not, but ill help you out based on what you explained.

From what i can gather from your explanation, what you attempt to accomplish is to copy a couple of tables from one db to another, if they can reach one another then its really simple, you could just create a DBLINK (http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_how_create_database_link.htm) and then do a SELECT AS INSERT from either side using the DBLINK for one of the tables and the local table as the receiver or sender. Its pretty straight forward.

But if its a one time thing i would just move the table with expdp and impdp since that will be a lot faster and a lot less strain on the DB.

If its something you need to maintain and keep updated, why not just add the DBLINK and use that on both sides, this will be dependent on network performance though.

If this is a bit out of you depth or you cant create dblinks due to restrictions, SQL Developer has had a database copy option for a while and you can go as far a copying individual tables, but its very heavy on the system where its being run (http://deepak-sharma.net/2014/01/12/copy-database-objects-between-two-databases-in-oracle-using-sql-developer/).